# Why would `dig` succeed, but `host`, `nslookup`, `curl`, `ping` all fail?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, iptables, docker

Since today, whenever I use any docker container with the `bridge` network interface, DNS resolutions seem to fail for certain utilities.

For instance, if I run:

```bsh
sudo docker run --rm \
    --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
    --log-driver json-file \
    --log-opt max-size=10m \
    --net=bridge --dns 9.9.9.9 \
    alpine \
    sh -c 'apk add curl bind-tools; printf "\nDATE:\n"; date; printf "\nRESOLV.conf\n"; cat /etc/resolv.conf; printf "\nDIG:\n"; dig api.nordvpn.com; printf "\nTRACE:\n"; dig +trace api.nordvpn.com; printf "\nHOST:\n"; host -va api.nordvpn.com; printf "\nNSLOOKUP:\n"; nslookup api.nordvpn.com; printf "\nCURL:\n"; curl api.nordvpn.com; printf "\nPING:\n"; ping -c 5 api.nordvpn.com; printf "\nWHOIS:\n"; whois api.nordvpn.com; printf "\nRESOLVE:\n"; systemd-resolve --status'
```

I get back:

```
DATE:
Sun Jul  4 05:58:26 UTC 2021

RESOLV.conf
nameserver 9.9.9.9

DIG:

; <<>> DiG 9.16.16 <<>> api.nordvpn.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60558
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;api.nordvpn.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
api.nordvpn.com.    30  IN  A   104.17.50.74
api.nordvpn.com.    30  IN  A   104.17.49.74

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 9.9.9.9#53(9.9.9.9)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 04 05:58:26 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 106


TRACE:

; <<>> DiG 9.16.16 <<>> +trace api.nordvpn.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           39329   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           39329   IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20210716050000 20210703040000 26838 . EB6qz8ilTb/5LvUg+xcuMuPL5KeZCcJNJxwD7kFGX/UiWdLuhk11/MZ3 R11asqSV7dC0pmttG+1h8kJG+IR022UaPBH7C/mV5vfvk5s0Vcp+DA7Y j3Rya2qm7UdTRPX3VEaL1C2ji/hnX2VIL1bU68t7OPNmhx/g0M9uwgXx hjL5jhPmRYTDInUHJThFn894VE0/HtkoIFZrWSDZjzMLf+j/CqWluRDI HH0JoOQVO5fSj7Vjtr9T67x6QG7C9qyMQ0xfTTkURkMQN4A1TEW5YGGB Ti6ypbLUmJQvHMKgFhoAc4Be/4dAm/spIlD4srIHMzECAayRXn2IXDsq xCCjaQ==
;; Received 717 bytes from 9.9.9.9#53(9.9.9.9) in 43 ms

api.nordvpn.com.    299 IN  A   104.17.50.74
api.nordvpn.com.    299 IN  A   104.17.49.74
;; Received 106 bytes from 199.7.83.42#53(l.root-servers.net) in 43 ms


HOST:
Trying "api.nordvpn.com"
Host api.nordvpn.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
Received 33 bytes from 9.9.9.9#53 in 43 ms

NSLOOKUP:
Server:     9.9.9.9
Address:    9.9.9.9#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   api.nordvpn.com
Address: 104.17.49.74
Name:   api.nordvpn.com
Address: 104.17.50.74
** server can't find api.nordvpn.com: SERVFAIL


CURL:
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.nordvpn.com

PING:
ping: bad address 'api.nordvpn.com'

WHOIS:
[Querying whois.iana.org:43 'api.nordvpn.com']
[Redirected to whois.verisign-grs.com]
[Querying whois.verisign-grs.com:43 'api.nordvpn.com']
[Querying whois.verisign-grs.com:43 'domain api.nordvpn.com']
[whois.verisign-grs.com]
No match for domain "API.NORDVPN.COM".
>>> Last update of whois database: 2021-07-04T05:58:26Z <<<

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.

TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and
automated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or
modify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry
Services' ("VeriSign") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for
information purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information
about or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not
guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide
by the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only
for lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data
to: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone,
or facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes
that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation,
repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly
prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.

RESOLVE:
sh: systemd-resolve: not found
```

I've already tried:

1. wiping docker and starting over
2. flushing dns and trying different nameservers
3. restarting the machine, the docker service, etc.
4. wiping firewall rules

To wipe the firewall, this is what I've used on the Raspberry Pi 4 host machine running Ubuntu Server arm64

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo ip6tables -t nat -F
sudo ip6tables -t mangle -F
sudo ip6tables -F
sudo ip6tables -X
sudo iptables -nvL

sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw status verbose

sudo systemctl restart docker
```

All the commands work fine on the host machine.

Docker network interfaces on the host machine are as expected:

```
> docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
73b916cb9b14   bridge    bridge    local
ea4702692896   host      host      local
03d46009da3e   none      null      local

> docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "73b916cb9b14ce7d31b091279f2763cba5e2856430ad10883ce93a2cefbf8eee",
        "Created": "2021-07-04T05:58:18.735577898Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`host` and `nslookup` make *several* separate DNS queries – one for each record type. They want to show you both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, so they need to make an A query and an AAAA query.

If you run `host -v api.nordvpn.com` (with the 'verbose' option to show responses in dig-like format), you will see that it is actually equivalent to these 3 commands in a row:

```
dig api.nordvpn.com A
dig api.nordvpn.com AAAA
dig api.nordvpn.com MX
```

Running `nslookup -debug api.nordvpn.com` will similarly show it querying for both A and AAAA records (although not MX).

If you look carefully at your Docker output, you will notice that the A query actually succeeds, it's the AAAA one which returns a SERVFAIL. So the failure is never visible in 'dig' because you never asked it to make AAAA queries.

There could be several explanations for the partially failing queries:

- Your resolver has some connectivity issues with the authoritative servers, but it happens to have results for A cached from earlier and is still able to return those.
- The authoritative servers of nordvpn.com are returning responses for A queries but failing to respond at all for AAAA queries.
- Your DNS requests are being intercepted and redirected to a different resolver, and that resolver blocks all AAAA queries under the  pretense of "not supporting IPv6" or "avoiding IPv6 VPN leaks" or similar.

Indeed your `dig +trace` output already shows that it's the 3rd case:

```
api.nordvpn.com.    299 IN  A   104.17.50.74
api.nordvpn.com.    299 IN  A   104.17.49.74
;; Received 106 bytes from 199.7.83.42#53(l.root-servers.net) in 43 ms
```

In trace mode, dig starts by contacting the root servers, where it's supposed to receive a referral response (one that points to the '.com' servers) and follow the chain.

But in your case, dig somehow immediately receives a direct answer with the requested A records. That's *not* how the root servers work – they are not *able* to provide such answers. The only time you would see this result is if your packets on port 53 are being redirected to a local resolver and you're not, in fact, talking to the DNS server that you think you're talking to.

---

Try making a DNS query at 192.0.2.1 or 203.0.113.1 – if you receive a response from this address you'll know it's not legitimate, because this address does not exist anywhere on the Internet.)

```
dig @192.0.2.1 google.com
```

Try making these queries to find out the name of the DNS server that you're actually talking to:

```
dig @9.9.9.9 hostname.bind chaos txt
dig @9.9.9.9 id.server chaos txt
```

(If talking to the *real* 9.9.9.9, you should see something like "res600.fra.rrdns.pch.net" as the id.server response.)

It might be worth trying to `traceroute --udp --port=53 9.9.9.9`; it will show normal results until it reaches the point where the packets are being redirected, nonsensical results afterwards.

Comment: Had to change the `traceroute` args as they were giving `traceroute: unrecognized option: udp BusyBox v1.33.1 () multi-call binary.`, to `traceroute -v -p 53 9.9.9.9`. Results of your suggestions can be viewed here: https://gist.github.com/balupton/9a1bd98cc9de175f407dd4e543ee80ac

Comment: The Busybox version of 'traceroute' does not support probing a fixed port, so it won't quite work here. Either way, you saw that you're getting DNS responses from nonexistent addresses, it's something to take up with whoever provides your Internet access.

Comment: Was able to solve this locally without contacting my ISP, details here: https://github.com/haugene/docker-transmission-openvpn/issues/1858#issuecomment-874429497 — thank you so much for your excellent answer, without it, I never would have been able to figure this out.