# nslookup throws error while dig doesn't

Tags: networking, dns

I have a situation where I have an A record for a subdomain (let's call it sub1.example.org), but I can't get a LetsEncrypt cert because of the following error:

`SERVFAIL looking up CAA for sub1.example.org - the domain's nameservers may be malfunctioning`

This A record is just like any other working A record I have on my hosting provider. It doesn't contain any special characters or some shenanigans like that.

When I do a `dig sub1.example.org` I get a response containing the following:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.6 <<>> sub1.example.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1656
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sub1.example.org.       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
sub1.example.org. 3600   IN      A       123.123.123.123

;; Query time: 39 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun Sep 25 05:41:36 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 68
```

The text `status: NOERROR` leads me to believe that there were no errors in the query or response. So far so good. However when I do an `nslookup sub1.example.org` I get the following:

```
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   sub1.example.org
Address: 123.123.123.123
** server can't find sub1.example.org: SERVFAIL
```

I have notified my dns hosting provider about this issue but they say that on their end it works perfectly. They sent me screenshots showing that running the exact same command using the exact same dns server didn't throw an error on their side. I have looked through some online nslookup tools and they also work fine (or don't show SERVFAIL errors).
What can I do?

I have tried nslookup on the following DNS servers:

- 1.1.1.1
- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4
- 9.9.9.9

All of the above throw a SERVFAIL error.

I have tried it both on my local machine (Ubuntu 22.04 WSL running on my home computer in The Netherlands) and on a VPS (Arch Linux running on a VPS in Germany). Both my own computer and the VPS give the same error.

I notified my DNS hosting provider again, but they told me that this issue only existed on my end.

[edit 1] Dig +trace output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> +trace sub1.example.org
;; global options: +cmd
.                       10223   IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       10223   IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20221008040000 20220925030000 20826 . KYH9d3k6QX5Pg7F5BYEPzUINa9sZdet1fbniXxBmsagZVZiDC6uEJrtw GvHZncSGcaPsksAJ/IhD6LYkwbE58nxoPxou+MZckn+fWOEQaWdlLMW9 l5kq70FJiJ6tnRW8B/5VebRT1GnS+F8OF2WmkXoSmfnipAfPZP+vxKLW 7NWk+7BlT/K9o/F6a5aeoFXjojx9JsXWnHshoouXeLDP9imbXmHVvZap y2edPOU7WkOVDAoIxQUTT4fLxB0LtPzT2BzHhgZmN+rRQ9L0g8SmqJxK qgHHUakVlV8BXNQFRkyCTXxM9zpxY5iD2w7JYEI+TrXSd7ABPEeajcGo u3VgzQ==
;; Received 525 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) in 10 ms

info.                   172800  IN      NS      a2.info.afilias-nst.info.
info.                   172800  IN      NS      d0.info.afilias-nst.org.
info.                   172800  IN      NS      b2.info.afilias-nst.org.
info.                   172800  IN      NS      c0.info.afilias-nst.info.
info.                   172800  IN      NS      a0.info.afilias-nst.info.
info.                   172800  IN      NS      b0.info.afilias-nst.org.
info.                   86400   IN      DS      5104 8 2 1AF7548A8D3E2950C20303757DF9390C26CFA39E26C8B6A8F6C8B1E7 2DD8F744
info.                   86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20221009040000 20220926030000 20826 . NLEzXygGkC9f8mxW7vk+pkNbAQLgKXFJNFmoPgYTMz4cs20sQL4SJV9y 8TF5HtaKMoW1IdL2u8NKOQN9dkeC/JqT5GpN0BQxpJfWUTm7t/x/DdKT 1WFYkqLuKZY/Jg1y+DIJ/gVObOD+QMDFZse4vnWO1apIKShkS5fqB9fs mS1SDZTGEOhxN8xgf12nJxPsz2ZVfOehiZew/mYjs6PcUqMz8RgmMB8v oj7KsQSeupZ29FEC5+Qkz8ax36pBNUOQB6s47sg3jld8Hp6r8aI8aACK KRg2xDYR39ZFczUA68z8bH2eJPCX/sf33A/bjkdo9V/o4B59qTP3rtIN 2rwNSg==
;; Received 826 bytes from 192.33.4.12#53(c.root-servers.net) in 20 ms
```

@harrymc, hope this helps, I'm not really sure what I'm looking at.

Comment: ServFail errors occur when there’s an error communicating with a DNS server, so this error is indeed on your side. Add the output of `dig +trace sub1.example.org`. For more debug, see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/804492/dns-servfail-at-some-of-nameservers).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your answer, I've added the requested output.

Comment: Follow also my above link as regarding the SOA and NS records. It would help to let us know your site's URL.

Comment: The URL in question is: wazuh.pieterhouwen.info. When querying the NS and SOA records for that I get nothing from 8.8.8.8, however when I query the NS and SOA records for another subdomain that is pointing to the same IP (pwmanager.pieterhouwen.info) I do get a valid response

Comment: I think you should compare the results for one subdomain that works, against one that doesn't, then ask your Support to fix up their DNS. This seems after all to be their fault.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that 'dig' makes one DNS query for a single type ("A" for IPv4-address records by default), whereas 'host' and 'nslookup' make ***two* queries, once for "A" records and once for "AAAA"** in order to show both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. If you look closely at its output, you will see that the first query succeeded, but the *second* query (for "AAAA" records) is the one that failed.

(The LetsEncrypt issuance servers make a yet different query, for "CAA" "issuance policy" records.)

Compare:

```
dig sub1.example.org A                 ; query IPv4 address
dig sub1.example.org AAAA              ; query IPv6 address
dig sub1.example.org CAA               ; query PKI issuance policy

nslookup sub1.example.org              ; query both IPv4 and IPv6
nslookup -debug sub1.example.org       ; ...and show the raw requests

nslookup -q=A sub1.example.org         ; query IPv4 address
nslookup -q=AAAA sub1.example.org      ; query IPv6 address
nslookup -q=CAA sub1.example.org       ; query PKI issuance policy (Linux only<1>)

<1> Beware that Windows nslookup.exe will not recognize 'CAA' as a valid type,
    so trying to use -q=CAA will achieve nothing on Windows.
```

Note that you should first test this against the *authoritative* nameservers for that domain, as they're the ones that actually produce the replies – not yet against public resolvers, which merely relay those replies. If you're not sure which servers are authoritative for your domain, do a "NS" query.

(Public resolvers would be the second thing to test, *only if* every one of the domain's authoritative nameservers returns the correct answers.)

Overall, it sounds like your domain's authoritative servers are mishandling queries for record types that they have no data for.

Normally, when a name exists in DNS but doesn't have records of that specific type, the authoritative server must still return a successful reply – merely one that has nothing (zero records) as the "answer". This applies even if the server doesn't *support* the specific record type being queried.

But if the resolvers are reporting SERVFAIL, this implies that your authoritative servers are either not replying at all, or replying with an error code – neither of which is a correct thing to do.

---

An almost-duplicate thread but of a slightly different situation (where a similar problem was only visible internally to the poster but not externally to LetsEncrypt's servers):

- [Why would `dig` succeed, but `host`, `nslookup`, `curl`, `ping` all fail?](https://superuser.com/questions/1660579/why-would-dig-succeed-but-host-nslookup-curl-ping-all-fail/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I issue the nslookup command to the authoritive nameserver I get a normal reply without SERVFAIL. I don't think that AAAA are the issue because my other subdomains for which I have succesfully obtained an SSL cert with certbot also don't have those records.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they have such records or not. What matters is how the server handles _queries_ for those records.